# jinstagram api - get complete user list

Tags: java, twitter, instagram, instagram-api

I am working on a java application that uses the jInstagram api. I can successfully login with my application, but when I want to get a list of users that follow a certain user, I can only gather 50 user Id's.

The code I am using to get 50 users that follow a user is this:

```
String userId = instagram.getCurrentUserInfo().getData().getId();
UserFeed feed = instagram.getUserFollowedByList(userId);
List<UserFeedData> users = feed.getUserList();
//iterate through the list and print each value. The print value is simply a user id.
```

I can then iterate through the list and print out 50 user Id's. This is fine, but I need to get a lot more user Id's.

From my research, in order to get more than 50 user Id's I must use the Pagination class. Here is what I put together.

```
    String userId = instagram.getCurrentUserInfo().getData().getId();
    UserFeed feed = instagram.getUserFollowList(userId);
    UserFeed recentData = instagram.getUserFollowedByListNextPage(feed.getPagination()); 

    int counter = 0;

    while(recentData.getPagination() != null && counter < 10){
        List<UserFeedData> a = recentData.getUserList();
         for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(a.get(i)); 
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

This Code works, but it gives an output like this for each user.

```
UserFeedData [id=316470004, profilePictureUrl=https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_316470004_75sq_1386826158.jpg, userName=thebeautifulwarrior, fullName=Dee Shower, website=http://www.totallifechanges.com/dns2015, bio=2015 the year to Reinvent & Restore! Lose 10 pounds in 10 days!!! Ask me how. Invest in yourself. E-mail: totallifechange2015@gmail.com]
```

For my program, I only want the id part. I know I can just parse the text and create a substring, but I want to do this more efficiently and retrieve the data from the api call instead. In the first snippet of code, that gives an output exactly how I need it. For example, the output for the code is "316470004" rather than the entire user information set.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the string representation of the entire UserFeedData object, rather than just the ID. Instead of `System.out.println(a.get(i));` use `System.out.println(a.get(i).getId());` to pull the user's ID.